# Play-Java OSGi Embeddable?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, osgi

**Context**

I have a set of bundles implemented by myself running on Felix (an implementation of the OSGi Framework). All bundles were written in Java.

**Question**

With the above scenario I decided to implement an MVC Application using the Play Framework for Java, my question is, how can I use my bundles running on Felix? Those bundles represent libraries that I need to develop my application.

I though about putting my Play App inside Felix, but that doesn't seem to be possible? 
Does anyone had this problem before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is vague....Any way, I will try to answer with what I had understood.

Using Maven[I took this assumption].

1. Create a parent maven project , which should server as your application frame.
2. Create Maven Modules Under this parent modules, which are all your libraries..
3. Start OSGI Embedded Framework inside your application frame
4. Expose API in application  frame to install , update and Stop you bundles.
5. Create Bundle Activators in Each Libraries modules.
6. Use BND tool to create bundle

Then Start your application. Install bundle and enjoy.....